# Meteor connect to DB problems

Tags: meteor

we are trying Meteor framework and in different environments we have problems with connections to Mongo database, which is hosted on external server. Now the problem occurred when I rebooted my laptop (Debian Linux). After reboot my application cannot read or insert anything in database and no errors are thrown. I can access the database with Robomongo shell. Also, we have autopublish on. How can I debug/fix this?

Comment: Are you setting the mongourl before starting your app? share the settings or configuration file if you have any.

Comment: Yes, I do set MONGO_URL like this: MONGO_URL=mongodb://myserver.net:27017/dbname. Everything was working just fine before I rebooted my laptop

Comment: I run additional test - inserting a document and reading it. this works. Now I found that that meteor actually writes to the local database (127.0.0.0:3001/meteor) despite me providing connection string to external database

Comment: `export MONGO_URL="mongodb://myserver:27017/db_name"` try this command.

Comment: this did the job, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exporting the MONGO_URL before starting your application.

`export MONGO_URL="mongodb://myserver:27017/db_name"`